# Issue with Telerik Ribbon Bar

Tags: c#, telerik

I'm trying out the Telerik controls, specifically the RibbonBar/RibbonForm and am running into a weird issue. In design view everything looks fine, like this:

[image]

But when I run the form everything on the RibbonBar is gone, looks like this:

[image]

Anyone have experience with these controls or have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding Groups (and maybe even a button or two) to some of the tabs?  In the first screenshot, the View tab doesn't have any groups.  Perhaps Telerik is not expecting an empty tab and so doesn't behave quite like you'd expect at runtime.  I would also check that you're using the latest version of their control - perhaps it's a bug they've fixed recently.  Finally, I'd try going through their '[Getting Started](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/ribbonbar-getting-started.html)' page to see if there might be a step you're missing.

Comment: I tried your idea and the groups/buttons show but the tabs are still missing. So it seems we're getting closer